# on the sum of inferior limits of two positive bounded sequences

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be two bounded sequences (not necessarily convergent) of positive real numbers.

Is it true that
$$\liminf_n \ a_n+\liminf_n \ b_n=\liminf_n \ (a_n+b_n)?$$

Any information/reference/comment will be appreciated.

Comment: Take $a_n=2+(-1)^n$ and $b_n=2+(-1)^{n+1}$.  They are bounded and positive.  What are their inferior limits, and the inferior limit of their sum?

Comment: @user539887 That's a very good hint. Why don't you post it as an answer (saying that it is a hint)?

Comment: @user539887: 1,1 and 4. Thanks

Comment: On the other hand, the inequality that you see is true in general: [Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO. Example: For $n\in \Bbb N$ let $a_{2n}=0$ and $a_{2n-1}=1$  and $b_n=a_{n+1}.$ Then $\lim \inf a_n=\lim \inf b_n=0$ but $a_n+b_n=1$ for every $n.$

Let $A_n= \inf_{m>n}a_m$ and $B_n=\inf_{m>n}b_m$ and $C_n=\inf_{m>n}(a_m+b_m).$ We have $A_n+B_n\leq C_n$ for every $n$, so $$\lim \inf a_n+\lim \inf b_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}A_n+\lim_{n\to \infty} B_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}(A_n+B_n)\leq$$ $$\leq  \lim_{n\to \infty}C_n=\lim \inf (a_n+b_n) .$$

Note that $\lim \inf a_n$ is the least value that any convergent  sub-sequence of $(a_n)_n$ can converge to. In order for $\lim \inf a_n +\lim \inf b_n=\lim \inf (a_n+b_n)$ it is necessary that there exists a strictly increasing $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ such  that $(a_{f(n)})_n$ converges to $\lim \inf a_n$ and such that $(b_{f(n)})_n$ converges to $\lim \inf b_n.$